# Linear Transformation: When T(v)=v

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a homework to do in which with a pre-defined transform I have to find a vector v that after the transformation equals itself: $T(v)=v$.

The transformation happens from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I found no clues yet from where to start.

I would like some hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what an eigen-vector is? In addition, what is the transformation you are looking at?

Comment: The Transform is: T(x,y,z) = (x + 2y + 2z,x + 2y - z,-x + y + 4z). And I'm fighting with the concept of eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: Just solve $T(v)-v=0$, which is easy. The solution is a whole _subspace_ from which you can choose any nonzero vector as your $v$. In fact your question does not say "nonzero", so alternatively you could just say $v=0$, which is bound to be a solution, and avoids the effort of solving anything. But I think they meant "nonzero" here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should construct the $3 \times 3$ matrix $M$ that represents $T$ and then solve the linear system
$$
M \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \end{pmatrix}
$$
You can find [here](http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/xmlearning/lecture_notes/matrices/from_linear_maps_to_matrices/from_linear_maps_to_matrices.php) a tutorial about matrices induced by linear transformations.

If you prefer a more direct approach, you should solve the linear system
$$
\begin{cases}
x+2y+2z=x \\
x+2y-z=y \\
-x+y+4z=z.
\end{cases}
$$
Now put everything on the left-hand side and solve the system with your favourite technique. You can use some gaussian reduction, or just backward substitution.

Comment: But I'm not geting a vector as a result, but another linear system... Am I doing the arithmetics wrong or is it like a representation of all vectors that when applied to T(v)=v?

Comment: You end up with a system that *you* should solve: find $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Comment: So, sorry for my dumbness, but I build the linear system, solve it to get another linear system and then solve this second system to get x, y and z in real values?